# How does iPod reproduction counter works?

Tags: itunes, ipod-classic

What triggers iPod reproduction counter to add +1? It is currently visible on iTunes and I was wondering if you have to listen untill the very end or a good portion of it, say half way through.

I don't know if that matters but my device is an iPod Classic 80 GB.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably it works the same way as it does in iTunes. Therefore, you must wait for the song to **change to the next one by ending** for the reproduction count to be increased by one.

**Clarifying Edit:** The counter increases each time the song changes by it self, either to *other one*, if there is, or to the *menu*, if it was the last song of a play list. Therefore, the portion of the song you've listened to has nothing to do with the reproduction counter increase.

Comment: Could you backup your opinion with some reliable reference?

Comment: Does the fact that I just tested it, work?

Comment: Did you test on iTunes or iPod?

Comment: Both, of course. I'll edit my answer to clarify a little bit.